# When will the Sherlock special episode air?

Tags: sherlock

What time will the special episode of the tv series, Sherlock air? And where can i see it?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is a highly localized request for locating content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonight (January 1st, 2016) at 9:00 PM  - UTC+00:00 on BBC1

Comment: It's 2016 bro (weeew!)

Comment: Whoops. I guess I got used to writing 2015 ...